# Как работать с wget через HTTP прокси на Ubuntu?

Tags: прокси, ubuntu

При попытке закачки файла

```
wget ...
```

выдается ошибка:

> Преобразование адреса ... ошибка: Имя или служба не известны.
>   wget: не могу получить адрес хоста «...»

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно задать переменную окружения `http_proxy`.

```
export http_proxy=прокси:порт
```